# DSpace add custom facet for grouped values

Tags: facet, dspace

I am using DSpace 5.4 and I am would like to make a new facet that displays under a category a range of values of a DC field.

For example DSpace contains 5 items and each has dc.testField as follows:

1. dc.testField = value1
2. dc.testField = value2
3. dc.testField = value3
4. dc.testField = value4
5. dc.testField = value5

For the purpose of the application in hand value1 and value2 are grouped to Group1, and value3, value4 and value5 are grouped to Group2.

Can I construct a facet that displays Group1 (2), Group2 (3) and upon select, the correct items to be returned?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The DSpace documentation indicates that you can define a facet to be a date field or a text field.

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Discovery#Discovery-Searchfilters&sidebarfacetsCustomization

The documentation indicates that date fields are grouped.

I do not see a mechanism to pass in your own grouping configurations.

You can also define a hierarchical facet in which your values contain taxonomy paths such as

- Group1::value1
- Group1::value2
- Group2::value3
- Group2::value4
- Group2::value5

See https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Discovery#Discovery-Hierarchical(taxonomiesbased)sidebarfacets